# simple example of mapbox offline in android doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, mapbox

**I've created an application in Android Studio and you install the SDK application
And the application runs normally, without any problems, but the establishment of the map loaded up ProgressBar to the middle and stands and shows me in the operation of this phrase that I have exceeded the required tile**

this is XML

```
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    mapbox:center_latitude="37.73359"
    mapbox:center_longitude="-119.58410"
    mapbox:style_url="mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v9"
    mapbox:zoom="10"
    mapbox:zoom_min="10"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

this is MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private boolean isEndNotified;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private MapView mapView;
private OfflineManager offlineManager;

// JSON encoding/decoding
public static final String JSON_CHARSET = "UTF-8";
public static final String JSON_FIELD_REGION_NAME = "FIELD_REGION_NAME";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Mapbox access token is configured here. This needs to be called either in your application
    // object or in the same activity which contains the mapview.
    MapboxAccountManager.start(this, getString(R.string.access_token));

    // This contains the MapView in XML and needs to be called after the account manager
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
            // Set up the OfflineManager
            offlineManager = OfflineManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this);

            // Create a bounding box for the offline region
            LatLngBounds latLngBounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
                    .include(new LatLng(37.7897, -119.5073)) // Northeast
                    .include(new LatLng(37.6744, -119.6815)) // Southwest
                    .build();

            // Define the offline region
            OfflineTilePyramidRegionDefinition definition = new OfflineTilePyramidRegionDefinition(
                    mapView.getStyleUrl(),
                    latLngBounds,
                    10,
                    20,
                    MainActivity.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

            // Set the metadata
            byte[] metadata;
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put(JSON_FIELD_REGION_NAME, "Yosemite National Park");
                String json = jsonObject.toString();
                metadata = json.getBytes(JSON_CHARSET);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to encode metadata: " + exception.getMessage());
                metadata = null;
            }

            // Create the region asynchronously
            offlineManager.createOfflineRegion(
                    definition,
                    metadata,
                    new OfflineManager.CreateOfflineRegionCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCreate(OfflineRegion offlineRegion) {
                            offlineRegion.setDownloadState(OfflineRegion.STATE_ACTIVE);

                            // Display the download progress bar
                            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
                            startProgress();

                            // Monitor the download progress using setObserver
                            offlineRegion.setObserver(new OfflineRegion.OfflineRegionObserver() {
                                @Override
                                public void onStatusChanged(OfflineRegionStatus status) {

                                    // Calculate the download percentage and update the progress bar
                                    double percentage = status.getRequiredResourceCount() >= 0
                                            ? (100.0 * status.getCompletedResourceCount() / status.getRequiredResourceCount()) :
                                            0.0;

                                    if (status.isComplete()) {
                                        // Download complete
                                        endProgress("Region downloaded successfully.");
                                    } else if (status.isRequiredResourceCountPrecise()) {
                                        // Switch to determinate state
                                        setPercentage((int) Math.round(percentage));
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(OfflineRegionError error) {
                                    // If an error occurs, print to logcat
                                    Log.e(TAG, "onError reason: " + error.getReason());
                                    Log.e(TAG, "onError message: " + error.getMessage());
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void mapboxTileCountLimitExceeded(long limit) {
                                    // Notify if offline region exceeds maximum tile count
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Mapbox tile count limit exceeded: " + limit);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(String error) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error);
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
    offlineManager.listOfflineRegions(new OfflineManager.ListOfflineRegionsCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onList(OfflineRegion[] offlineRegions) {
            if (offlineRegions.length > 0) {
                // delete the last item in the offlineRegions list which will be yosemite offline map
                offlineRegions[(offlineRegions.length - 1)].delete(new OfflineRegion.OfflineRegionDeleteCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDelete() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Yosemite offline map deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(String error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "On Delete error: " + error);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onListError: " + error);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

// Progress bar methods
private void startProgress() {

    // Start and show the progress bar
    isEndNotified = false;
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void setPercentage(final int percentage) {
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressBar.setProgress(percentage);
}

private void endProgress(final String message) {
    // Don't notify more than once
    if (isEndNotified) {
        return;
    }

    // Stop and hide the progress bar
    isEndNotified = true;
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // Show a toast
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

[this is problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLqFq.png)

Comment: Please include the logs of the issue you are having in the description of the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How using offline map in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804868/how-using-offline-map-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug but a limitation we impose on users so they cannot download all of earth for example at once. You can read more about the [tile limit here](https://www.mapbox.com/help/mobile-offline/#tile-ceiling--limits) and use the [tile calculator](https://www.mapbox.com/labs/offline-estimator/) to estimate the region. If you want to download a larger region you will need to break up your region into smaller downloads.